# Search and replace with 3 variables from one range with 3 cols

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with a rather complex search and replace function, which is made up of one large table with 3 columns defining the 1) sheet where to SnR, 2) search term, 3) replacement word. I am testing on a `Test` sheet with 10 entries, but cant get the script to process any of the cells in range...

```
Sub FART_find_and_replace_text()
Dim sheet_name, label_old, label_new As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheetrng As Range

    Set sheet_rng = Range(Sheets("Test").Range("B65536").End(xlUp), Range(Sheets("Test").Range("B5")))   'all queries
    'Set sheet_name = Range(Sheets("Test").Range("B65536").End(xlUp), Range(Sheets("Test").Range("B5")))   'sheet name
    'Set label_old = Range(Sheets("Test").Range("D65536").End(xlUp), Range(Sheets("Test").Range("D5")))   'search term
    'Set label_new = Range(Sheets("Test").Range("E65536").End(xlUp), Range(Sheets("Test").Range("E5")))   'replacement

    i = 0   'set counter to 0

    For Each cell In sheet_rng
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value)
            .Activate
            .Cells.Find(What:=cell.Offset(0, 2).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            .ActiveCell.Replace What:=cell.Offset(0, 2), Replacement:=cell.Offset(0, 3), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        End With

        i = i + 1

    Next

End Sub
```

I am running Office on MAC which I have been told is not great with VBA, but I sadly have no choice and appreciate all the help I can get.

Thank you

EDIT:
here a screenshot of my sample data
[image]

Note: my sheet name is in A, search value in C and replace value in D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data is in B, D and E columns.

Following is the macro for A, C and D columns.

```
Sub FindReplaceMutiValMutiSheet()
Dim FRdata As Range, TempSh As Worksheet, TempData As Range, FRarr
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set FRdata = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LRow)

'Copy FRData to temporary sheet and assign it to TempData

Set TempSh = Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
TempSh.Range("A1").Resize(FRdata.Rows.Count, FRdata.Columns.Count).Value = FRdata.Value
Set TempData = TempSh.Range("A1:D" & LRow)

'Sort TempData on "Sheet Name" (A) and "Search" (C) Columns
With TempSh.Sort
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(TempData(1, 1), TempData(TempData.Rows.Count, 1)) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(TempData(1, 3), TempData(TempData.Rows.Count, 3)) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range(TempData.Address)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

End With

'Array of TempData Values
FRarr = TempData.Value

'Delete TempSh as no longer required.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempSh.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Find and replace loop basded on FRarr array
For i = 2 To UBound(FRarr, 1)
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> FRarr(i, 1) Then Sheets(FRarr(i, 1)).Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    Cells.Replace What:=FRarr(i, 3), Replacement:=FRarr(i, 4), LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Next

End Sub
```

Tested it on following sample data; works fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have adjusted my data look like your sample, however, I am getting an out of range error for this line `If ActiveSheet.Name <> FRarr(i, 1) Then Sheets(FRarr(i, 1)).Activate` when trying to activate `Sheets(FRarr(i, 1))`.

Comment: Does the Sheet named in the data exist in the workbook? . Are the Sheet Names in the First column of the array?

Comment: yes. funnily enough, the 3 sample rows actually get replaced, but the macro stops after that.

Comment: Can you pleas add a screen shot of the sample data in the question .. with column and row headers and Sheet Tabs?

Comment: I noticed that your data uses headers, so I included mine as well. all 3 test rows are being searched and replaced, its just after that operation that the macro fails.

Comment: Yes the data in my sample contains headers in the first row and the loop starts from the second row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213893/discussion-between-armitage2k-and-naresh-bhople).